# How to get Contex reveal work in org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs26

Having a hard time figuring out what C-c C-r does `context reveal`

Manual says "With a prefix argument show, on each level, all sibling headings. With a double prefix argument, also show the entire subtree of the parent."

1. When all the Headings are collapsed and I do C-c C-r on a Heading 1

   - nothing happens
2. If I try it on a Heading2 or Heading3 when it is collapsed

   - nothing happens
3. If I try C-u 2 C-c C-r on a second level heading

   - Do I get to see all Heading 2 siblings with the current heading fully expanded ?
   - How can I make this work ?

     - Or does this work only in `agenda views` or `sparse trees` only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. its for sparse trees.

After `C-c /` when the cursor is on the the highlighted entry, `C-c C-r` works. :)